# Invalid value 'armeabi' in $(AndroidSupportedAbis). This ABI is no longer supported. Xamarin.Forms - VS2019

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, build-error, visual-studio-2019

I have a Mobile App built with Xamarin.Forms
when I am trying to upgrade my project from VS2017 to VS2019

I get this error in **Android Project**

> Invalid value 'armeabi' in $(AndroidSupportedAbis). This ABI is no longer supported. Please update your project properties

I tried to delete **bin** and **obj** folders to force the project to rebuild everything, but the error still appears

**Can I get an explanation about the error above and how to solve it?**

Note: **the error doesn't appear in VS2017**

Comment: Android removed `armeabi` in recent releases and old projects may still have it within their supported abi list. You'll have to update those to not include `armeabi`. Builds with VS2017 do support it still, but since you're on a new VS2019 build, we removed this to adhere to Android. `armeabi - Deprecated in r16. Removed in r17. No hard float.` (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`armeabi` is deprecated and your Android project should target `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` at a minimum in your release builds destined for the Play Store.

You can directly edit your `.csproj` and remove the `armeabi` from within the `AndroidSupportedAbis` tags:

```
<AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>
```

Or you can open the Android Build settings in the IDE and it will auto-update it for you:

- [Targeting 64 bit architectures on Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54537615/4984832)

Answer (score 39):

It can be adjusted in 3 steps.

Step 1 - Right-click on Android Project and Click Properties:

[image: Right click on Android Project and Click Properties]

Step 2 to 4:
[image: follow Step 2 to 4]

Step 5 - Uncheck armeabi: 
[image: Uncheck armeabi]

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, right-click on your project under the Solution Explorer and select Properties. Under the Android Options page check the Packaging properties section and verify that Use Shared Runtime is disabled (turning this off allows you to explicitly select which ABIs to support). Click the Advanced button and, under Supported architectures, check the architectures that you want to support:
tip: if you are unaware of arm architectures checking all will remove errors