# Xamarin Deployment failed and ArchitectureNotSupportedBySharedRuntime when trying to debug on mobile phone

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment, usb-debugging

I have a problem that I really can't understand what causes this problem.
I get this error when I try to debug a xamarin app to my physical android mobile phone. 
This is the blank app that you get when you first create a project. So I have not added
one line of code to this application. I have tried with everything I can think of for 2
days and I just can't manage to understand the problem:

**Error     ADB0000:  Deployment failed
Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: ArchitectureNotSupportedBySharedRuntime**

**My phone:**
CPU Architecture: ARMv7 Processor rev3 (v7l)
Cores: 2
Instruction Sets: armeabi-v7a, armeabi
Kernel Architecture: armv7l

*(I have enabled debugging mode in the Developer Options on the mobile phone)*

As seen in the image. I choose: "armeabi" and "armeabi-v7a" and I have also tried one at a time with same error. 
That should be the same Architecture as my phone has.

[image]

I also have set the minimum API as:
Android 4.4 (API Level 19 - Kit Kat)
[image]

Comment: have you tried disabling the shared runtime?

Comment: Yes I tried that also and when I do that, I get those errors: `ADB0000:  Deployment failed, Mono.AndroidTools.AdbException: device '0123456789ABCDEF' not found, This ABI ('armeabi') is deprecated and will be removed in the next release. Please update your project properties`

Comment: Based on your error message, armeabi is deprecated and your Android project should target `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` at a minimum in your release builds destined for the Play Store. For the setting details, you can refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/56197862/10627299

Comment: Leon Lu, you are the best! This worked! I tried for 2 days, all possible combinations but not this one. I am very happy for your answer! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Andreas I move my comment to answer, please mark it, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error message, `armeabi` is deprecated and your Android project should target `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a` at a minimum in your release builds destined for the Google Play Store.

Please edit your `.csproj` and remove the `armeabi` from within the AndroidSupportedAbis tags:

`<AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>`

Comment: @Andreas Are there any update for this issue, please mark it, it will help others who have similar issue.